# rotating proxies with scrapy with authentication

Tags: python, scrapy

just a noob question but I can't seem to find the answer googling. how can i  use this package
https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-rotating-proxies/
if the proxy requires a user/password?
do I just put it in the rotating list like that?

```
ROTATING_PROXY_LIST = [
    'https://username:password@proxy:port',
    'https://username:password@proxy:port',
    # ...
]
```

thanks

Comment: [That’s correct](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware).

Comment: yea after testing figured it out thank you

Answer (score 3):

what worked for me is using the rotating proxy list path:

```
ROTATING_PROXY_LIST_PATH = 'path/to/proxylist.txt'
```

and then in the text file, I have my list formatted like this:

```
USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT
USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT
USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT
```